# language switching invalid?

Tags: magento-1.9, language, switcher

Magento language switching invalid:

1. Click Chinese :
   http://127.0.0.1/porto/vendors/index/login/?___store=english&___from_store=cn => display English
2. Click English :
   http://127.0.0.1/porto/vendors/index/login/?___store=english&___from_store=cn
   => Display Chinese

My store configuration is set to:

- default config: Chinese
- main website: Chinese
- english store: English
- chinese store: Chinese

Answer (score 2):

Use short code like **en** for english. It have to match your lang folder code

Comment: This is wrong. The so called "language switch" is a store switch and you can use whatever store code the store has. The language is defined by the store, not the short code.

Comment: use en and cn ,  same is

Answer (score 2):

Make sure sessions work, which means cookies should work. Not all browsers like localhost or up addresses for cookies.

If everything seems to be in order, follow the code from Mage:: run with a debugger or your mind. It should not take long before Magento has selected the store to run.

If the correct store is run, but the language is incorrect, I suspect you are using a full cache implementation that had not been told yet to never cache pages with the store parameter in the URL.

If it selects the wrong store, you may already have seen why. Most likely culprit is a rewrite by an extension or a auto loader override in app/code/local/Mage.

If you still can't figure it, follow up with more details about what you've found out with these tests.